# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 Express have Intellisense?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I don't have any Intellisense in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Management Studio - is this supposed to work?

I am connecting to a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database on the same machine (no other databases here at home) and I have no Intellisense.

Just wondering if it's supposed to work or is Express crippled?

Answer (score 4):

try this to fix the problem, has to do with SP1 for vs2010 if you have that setup [FIX: The IntelliSense feature in SSMS 2008 R2 may stop working after you install Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482)

Comment: Yep that was my problem - brand new install of Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 SP1 etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Intellisense only works if you are connected to a database that is SQL2008 or higher.  If you use management studio to connect to a sql2000 or sql2005 server, there will be no intellisense.

Also, there is an option to turn it on/off.  In SQL Server Management Studio, click Tools -> Options. Expand "Text Editor" and click on "All Languages".  Make suer "Auto list members and Parameter information" are both checked.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I knew it had to be >= 2008 but my question was specifically about Express

Answer (score 0):

It has Intellisense on my machine, but only on a few servers. I think you need to enable some permissions for it to work.